# How to find an unitary transformation of $A$ that minimize $(A'_{i,i}-1)^2$?

Tags: matrices, transformation

Is there a way to find an unitary transformation
$$ A'=U^+AU $$ 
that  minimize:
$$(A'_{i,i}-1)^2$$

In other words, the diagonal elements must be similar to one: $A'_{i,i} \approx 1$

Any hint?

Thank you!

Comment: What about the identity matrix?

Comment: Do you want to minimize a particular diagonal element, minimize all at once, or minimize their total?

Comment: I want to minimize that term for all the diagonal elements, I don't care if I should use an iterative procedure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume in the following that $A$ is a hermitian matrix. Then the matrix $A' = U ^{\dagger} A U$ is again hermitian.

Let set of possible diagonals value $ (d_1, \ldots d_n)$ achieved by the matrices of form $A' = ^{\dagger} A U$  forms a polytope in the hyperplane $\sum d_i = \text{trace} A$. 
This is an important theorem of Horn.

The closest point to the point $(1,\ldots, 1)$ is the one with all coordinates equal. 
It can be obtained for $U = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} (\exp 2 \pi i\cdot  k\cdot  l /n)_{0\le k,l \le n-1}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to have some reference for better understand what you said, maybe some reference not too hard to study (I'm doing a phd in quantum chemistry). If I'm right, $k$ and $l$ are from $0$ to $n-1$, but the elements of the $U$ matrix are from $1$ to $n$, do I need to shift them one to one?

Comment: No worries. About the matrix $U$, it is the Fourier transform on functions on the group $\mathbb{Z}/n$. You can shift the indexes.  I took it only because it is unitary and  all its elements have the same absolute value $1/\sqrt{n}$. In some dimensions you can do it with unitaries with real entries --multiples of Hadamard matrices.

Comment: I will get some precise references and  add more to the answer.

Comment: Hi orangeskid, I'm sorry to bother you. Did you find the references you were talking about? Thank you very much!

Comment: Doubly Stochastic Matrices and the Diagonal of a Rotation Matrix
Author: Alfred Horn   American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 76, No. 3 (Jul., 1954),